# Module Reference Error

Tags: verilog

I am attempting to initialize my memory to zeros so that later I can initialize my memory with a file.  My memory is composed of sram blocks, each of which is 32-lines and 32-bits per line.  The sram32x32 have a member in the module called `reg [31:0] mem [31:0]`.  Each bank contains some `blocksPerBank` amount of these 32x32 blocks.  There are `sramBanks=8` banks right now.

Consecutive memory addresses interleave through each bank.  After going through each bank, it goes to the next line.  After going through all of the lines, it goes to the next block.  After that, it rolls back around (this can be seen in the nested for-loop ordering in the `initial` block).  Here is how I instantiate and initialize my memory.  I think this should be sufficient information, but let me know if more is necessary.

```
  generate
    for(i=0; i<sramBanks; i=i+1) begin : bank
      sram32x32$ block [blocksPerBank-1:0]
        (obtag[tagLineMSB:tagLineLSB], 
         cdb[i*32 +: 32], 1'b0, 
         FSM_memWR, FSM_ceEnAdj
        );
    end

    integer b, l, k;
    initial begin
      for(b=0; b<blocksPerBank; b=b+1) begin : bpb
        for(l=0; l<32; l=l+1) begin : ln
          for(k=0; k<sramBanks; k=k+1) begin : sbnk
            bank[k].block[b].mem[l] = 32'b0;
          end
        end
      end
    end
  endgenerate
```

But the error I get is:

```
Error-[XMRE] Cross-module reference resolution error
MainMemory.v, 149
  Error found while trying to resolve cross-module reference.
  token 'bank'.  Originating module 'MainMemory'.
  Source info: bank[k].block[b].mem[l] = 32'b0;
```

How do I reference the modules from the generate loop while in my `initial` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of an arrayed module instance needs to constant. Therefore, `b` and `k` need to be `genvar`.

```
genvar b, k;
generate
  for(b=0; b<blocksPerBank; b=b+1) begin : bpb
    for(k=0; k<sramBanks; k=k+1) begin : sbnk
      integer l;
      initial begin
        for(l=0; l<32; l=l+1) begin : ln
          bank[k].block[b].mem[l] = 32'b0;
        end
      end
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Note that `integer l` is defined inside the for-loop. Each look creates a `l` visable to the local scope. This prevents clobbering when the generated `b*k` initial blocks execute in parallel.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know about the constness problem, but it makes other things hard now.  This solution swaps around my for-loops, which then iterates over my memory space in some non-consecutive manner.  I have to iterate over each bank first, then each line after that, and then each block after that.  Do I need to reorganize how I instantiate my modules in order to do this?

Comment: Basically, a memory address is formed like this:
`{garbage, block, line, bank, 2'b00}`.  The 2 LBSs are from 32-bit alignment.

Comment: You create some kind of translation layer; such as a script to split the memory file into chunks, a relational reference model, or making the memory model smart enough to correctly parse memory file. Things like SystemVerilog, Perl's [EP3](http://search.cpan.org/~gspivey/Text-EP3-Verilog-1.00/Verilog.pm), Ruby's [eRuby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/eruby.htm)/[ruby_it](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_it), Python's [prepro](http://corner-case.com/indproj/prepro.html), GNU Makefile, etc., can help.